# Retrieving even a single iOS ECG measurement w/ voltage data causes app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, healthkit

I am trying to retrieve iOS ECG data including voltage information within my Flutter app.
I have tried both the `health` package and the `health-kit-reporter` package, however both crash when I try to retrieve just a single ECG reading. I have tracked them back and they crash within the Swift file at the line `let voltageQuery = HKElectrocardiogramQuery(ecgSample) { (query, [result][1]) in` ie. when it's actually retrieving the data (relevant Apple documentation here).

Whenever I do it, I get the memory error:

```
* thread #3, queue = 'com.apple.HealthKit.HKHealthStore.client.0x281d32630', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
error: memory read failed for 0x0
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

I get the same error on both an iPhone 7 and iPhone 11 (both running min. iOS 14) using various different readings.

Does anyone know how to avoid this happening please?

I'm not sure if say there's a way to retrieve a part of a reading for example, as I think the app is just struggling to handle the size of variable, particularly as if I don't request voltage data, the app doesn't fail.

My Flutter code calling in this case the `health-kit-reporter` package:

```
List<Electrocardiogram> electrocardiogramList = [];
electrocardiogramList = await HealthKitReporter.electrocardiogramQuery(
              predicate,
              withVoltageMeasurements: true);
```

`health-kit-reporter`'s Swift code calling HealthKit:

```
let query = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: type,
            predicate: predicate,
            limit: limit,
            sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors
        ) { (query, data, error) in
            guard
                error == nil,
                let results = data as? [HKElectrocardiogram]
            else {
                resultsHandler([], error)
                return
            }
            var ecgs: [Electrocardiogram]
            switch withVoltageMeasurements {
            case true:
                ecgs = []
                var ecgsError: Error?
                let group = DispatchGroup()
                for ecgSample in results {
                    var measurments = [Electrocardiogram.VoltageMeasurement]()
                    group.enter()
                    let voltageQuery = HKElectrocardiogramQuery(ecgSample) { (query, result) in
                        switch(result) {
                        case .measurement(let voltageMeasurement):
                            if let measurment = try? Electrocardiogram.VoltageMeasurement(voltageMeasurement: voltageMeasurement) {
                                measurments.append(measurment)
                            }
                        case .done:
                            if let ecg = try? Electrocardiogram(electrocardiogram: ecgSample, voltageMeasurements: measurments) {
                                ecgs.append(ecg)
                            }
                            group.leave()
                        case .error(let error):
                            ecgsError = error
                            group.leave()
                        @unknown default:
                            ecgsError = HealthKitError.notAvailable("Unknown case of Electrocardiogram.VoltageMeasurement result")
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                    healthStore.execute(voltageQuery)
                }
                group.notify(queue: .global()) {
                    resultsHandler(ecgs, ecgsError)
                }
            case false:
                ecgs = Electrocardiogram.collect(results: results)
                resultsHandler(ecgs, nil)
            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll need to post your code. It looks like a null pointer error, but we can't say more than that unless you show us how you call the API.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JeremyP - added the relevant code now.

Comment: Following the documentation you linked, I see "After retrieving an HKElectrocardiogram sample, you can access the voltage measurements ..." I've not used that kit, but I assume from that comment that retrieving a sample is a prerequisite to querying the voltage. Probably the sampling method populates the variables you're trying to access. In other words ecgSample must be defined. Also, I've not used Flutter, so I can't help with that part. What populates results?

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist @VictorEngel - yes your guess is correct - I've added more of the code to provide full context. If the `withVoltageMeasurements` switch is false, the code works no problem, but if it's true, it fails with the error when calling the `HKElectrocardiogramQuery` function.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar function for Cordova (another cross-platform mobile app platform) and was running into the same issue. As soon as I defined the voltageQuery it would crash on TestFlight for iOS 16.6.1 (though not later OSs).

Eventually I downgraded Xcode from 15 to 14.3.1 and this solved the crashing issue. You can download older Xcode versions here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
You'll also want to make sure to download the corresponding Command Line Tools (14.3.1) and then set your Xcode to use those in the Settings > Locations > Command Line Tools.

This is only a temporary fix, but I'm assuming there is an issue on the Apple side with their HealthKit API when targeting the older iOS versions. Hopefully this helps you get your project going.